# JSON is reordering returned list

Tags: json

I have some jQuery that will change the contents of a select box depending upon the value of another select box (it uses AJAX). The PHP is returning the array how I want (sorted by TypeDescriptionData.name), but the list is getting re-ordered somewhere in the JS. Any ideas?

PHP Call:

```
public function get_descriptions_by_type($typeId) {
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $this->loadModel('TypeDescriptionData');

    $data = array();

    $this->TypeDescriptionData->contain();
    $descriptions = $this->TypeDescriptionData->find('list', array('conditions' => array('type_data_id' => $typeId), 'order' => 'name ASC'));

    if(isset($descriptions) && is_array($descriptions)) {
        foreach($descriptions as $x => $y) {
            $data[$x] = $y;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Here's the JSON right after the json_encode php call above:

```
{
   "1":"FD 50",
   "9":"Hypercom T4210",
   "2":"Hypercom T7P",
   "8":"Hypercom T7Plus",
   "10":"Nurit 2085",
   "11":"Nurit 8400",
   "12":"Nurit 8400 Lite",
   "17":"Other Terminal",
   "13":"Verifone Tranz 330",
   "14":"Verifone Tranz 380",
   "15":"Verifone Vx510",
   "16":"Verifone Vx510 LE"
}
```

Here's the JS:

```
$('#TypeType').change(function() {
    $('#TypeDescription').find('option').remove().end();
    $.ajax({
        url:'/TypeData/get_descriptions_by_type/' + $(this).val(),
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( json ) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
            $.each(json, function(i, value) {
                $('#TypeDescription').prepend($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', i));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And here's the JSON if I add "console.log(JSON.stringify(json));" immediately after the "success: function( json ) {" in the JS above:

```
{
   "1":"FD 50",
   "2":"Hypercom T7P",
   "8":"Hypercom T7Plus",
   "9":"Hypercom T4210",
   "10":"Nurit 2085",
   "11":"Nurit 8400",
   "12":"Nurit 8400 Lite",
   "13":"Verifone Tranz 330",
   "14":"Verifone Tranz 380",
   "15":"Verifone Vx510",
   "16":"Verifone Vx510 LE",
   "17":"Other Terminal"
}
```

Comment: what does the raw JSON look like? I.E. the content of the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A json object is an associative array, so the two objects are actually equivalent. Basically the computer doesn't remember the order, just key/value pairs. If order really matters to you then you need to use some other kind of structure. For example you could embed an array:

```
{
    "beaches" : [
        {"key" : "1", "value" : "FD 50"},
        {"key" : "2", "value" : "Hypercom T7P"},
        {"key" : "8", "value" : "Hypercom T7Plus"}
    ]
}
```